# Linux USB keyboard with individual num key settings

Tags: linux, keyboard, numlock

I have a computer hooked up to the TV, with a wireless keyboard. The same computer has a regular monitor with a regular keyboard.

Now the wireless keyboard is one of these compact ones without a dedicated num block. Starting up, the num key is on, which means pressing the J, K, L key enters 1, 2, 3 (because the num block is mapped to the right part of that keyboard. So in order to enter something, I have to turn off the num key on the wireless keyboard. But when I’m on the regular keyboard, I pretty much like the num key to be on.

Is there a way to have separate settings for the individual keyboards? I’m not talking about language mappings, but simply a way to avoid having the num key on keyboard 1 also turning on the num key on keyboard 2? (under X11, that is.)

Operating system is opensuse, with current xorg, and xfce4.